# In gridview is not displaying the first row

Tags: c#, asp.net

In gridview that am try to displaying the data in the database but it is ignoring the first row from the tabel & taking the rest of row.., plz suggest me what to do..
below is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBLibrary obj = new DBLibrary();
        String Parent = (string)Session["parentName"];
        String ss = "Select StudentId from Tbl_Parents where parentName='" + Parent + "'";
        SqlDataReader dr6 = obj.ExecuteReader(ss);
        dr6.Read();
        string id = dr6[0].ToString();
        string bind = "SELECT AnuFeeMaster.StudentId, Tbl_Student.SName, AnuFeeMaster.Month, AnuFeeMaster.Year, AnuFeeMaster.FeeAmount, " +
                    " AnuFeeMaster.PaidAmount FROM  AnuFeeMaster INNER JOIN Tbl_Student ON AnuFeeMaster.StudentId = Tbl_Student.StudentId where ( AnuFeeMaster.StudentId ='" + id + "')";//and (AnuFeeMaster.ChkDate='" + date.ToString() + "') ";
        SqlDataReader dr = obj.ExecuteReader(bind);
        dr.Read();
        gv1.DataSource = dr;
        gv1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: did you try to execute the query and see the result? is it also missing the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `dr.Read();` line.

You are passing the reader already advanced with one position.

Comment: @Vinay If the answer is correct, mark it as answer. It will help anyone in your position in the future